# Problems/errors with Kurento Node.JS examples

Tags: node.js, kurento, video-conferencing

I have been trying to write a Node.JS server/client based on the Kurento Media Server, WebRTC conference example.  I couldn't get my code to work right, so I thought I would start off by just taking the original example code, setting that up on my dev computer, watching it work, and then slowly making small changes until I got to the way I needed the software to work.

The problem is that I can't get the "webrtc-video-conference-tutorial-kurento" (or the "kurento-one2many-call") example code to work, even if it's completely unmodified.  I have tried setting up the current version of Kurento on 2 separate development systems (Ubuntu 18, and Windows 10).  Both of them encounter the same errors (code: 40401... Ice Candidate Error).

The exact error text that I am getting is listed below.  I would be very greateful for any help you can offer.

```
Trace: Error: Error adding candidate
at C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-client\lib\KurentoClient.js:361:24
at Object.dispatchCallback [as callback] (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:546:9)
at processResponse (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:667:15)
at RpcBuilder.decode (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:723:5)
at Stream.transportMessage (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:208:10)
at Stream.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Stream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
at drain (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\through\index.js:36:16)
at Stream.stream.queue.stream.push (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\through\index.js:45:5)
at WebsocketStream.onMessage (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\websocket-stream\index.js:45:15) {
```

code: 40401,
data: { type: 'ICE_ADD_CANDIDATE_ERROR' }
}
at WebRtcEndpoint.noop (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-client-elements\lib\WebRtcEndpoint.js:35:22)
at callback2 (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\promisecallback\index.js:27:25)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
Message received:  candidate
Trace: Error: Error adding candidate
at C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-client\lib\KurentoClient.js:361:24
at Object.dispatchCallback [as callback] (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:546:9)
at processResponse (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:667:15)
at RpcBuilder.decode (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:723:5)
at Stream.transportMessage (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-jsonrpc\lib\index.js:208:10)
at Stream.emit (events.js:315:20)
at Stream.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:467:12)
at drain (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\through\index.js:36:16)
at Stream.stream.queue.stream.push (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\through\index.js:45:5)
at WebsocketStream.onMessage (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\websocket-stream\index.js:45:15) {
code: 40401,
data: { type: 'ICE_ADD_CANDIDATE_ERROR' }
}
at WebRtcEndpoint.noop (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\kurento-client-elements\lib\WebRtcEndpoint.js:35:22)
at callback2 (C:\Dev\X-Platform\WebDev\webrtc-video-conference-example\src\node_modules\promisecallback\index.js:27:25)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)